# How to set min and max value in bootstrap timePicker?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, timepicker, bootstrap-vue

I'm using vue-bootstrap in my app, and have 2 fields in a form to fill with time. For it, I'm using **b-form-timepicker** component of bootstrap, but it appears to not have a function to set min and max values, to limit the range of hours can be selected. The better solution in this case is to use another component than bootstrap nativo timepicker?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could approach this is to use `isBetween()` from **moment.js** and the `:state` validation state to provide a visual cue and block form submission if false:

**Template:**

```
<b-form-timepicker v-model='time' :state='isValidTime' >
```

**Script:**

```
import moment from 'moment';

...

format = 'hh:mm:ss';
time = null;
minTime = moment('10:30:00', this.format);
maxTime = moment('14:40:00', this.format);

get isValidTime() {
  return moment(this.time, this.format).isBetween(this.minTime, this.maxTime);
}
```

You also have the `@input` event at your disposal which will fire when the time value changes. You could put similar validation code there.

Sample validation state behavior using **BootstrapVue**:
[image]

Learn more about [validation states here](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form#validation).

Answer (score 0):

Please try these codes, To How to set the min and max values in the bootstrap time picker?

```
<div class="md-form">
  <input placeholder="Selected time" type="text" id="input-limited-range" class="form-control timepicker">
  <label for="input-limited-range">Try me</label>
</div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#input-limited-range').pickatime({
    twelvehour: true,
    min: "8:20am",
    max: "5:15pm"
  });
});
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.