# how to set start and end values in b-vue-timepicker

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, timepicker, bootstrap-vue

I need to set a time range for the [bootstrap-vue-timepicker](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-timepicker).

The default component begins at `00` but I need to start it like at `05` or `07`.

[image]

This way the user doesn't have to make the unnecessary click events every time because he is limited by a time range.

I only found this thread on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66323491/how-to-set-min-and-max-value-in-bootstrap-timepicker), but the solutions use jQuery or only validate the input.

Do you have any suggestions for solutions?

When I inspect the object I see the labels: `aria-valuemin="0"` & `aria-valuemax="23"` but changes unfortunately don't bring anything.

update:

this functionality is on their [roadmap since at least Aug 2020](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5089) :(

---

here is the template code:

```html
<div class="mt-3">
  <label><strong>{{ $t("desired time") }}</strong></label>

  <b-form-timepicker 
    v-model="desiredTime"
    :placeholder="$t('timepicker placeholder')"
    no-flip
    no-close-button
    offset="0"
    inutes-step="15"
    class="mb-3"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: I see the issue, but could you please explain why can't you use `desiredTime: "05:00:00"` ?

Comment: @ImanShafiei I think the OP wants to enforce min/max values on the component (preventing values out of range).

Comment: yes, I would like to set min/max values as mentioned by tony, @ImanShafiei

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came up with one solution, I think it's hacky, but probably with some modification, it can be an approach. I used `watch` to check the value of `disiredTime` and wrote some simple logic.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      desiredTime: "05:00:00",
      min_hour_limit: 5,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    desiredTime() {
      let splitted_time = this.desiredTime.split(":")
      let hour = splitted_time[0]
      let minute = splitted_time[1]
      let second = splitted_time[2]
      if (Number(hour) < this.min_hour_limit) {
        hour = this.min_hour_limit
      }

      this.desiredTime = `${hour}:${minute}:${second}`
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <b-form-timepicker v-model="desiredTime" no-flip no-close-button offset="0" minutes-step="15" class="mb-3" :hour12="false" />
</div>
```

I just want to give you the idea and the logic that I used in `watch` is not clean. By using some alerts, you can notify the users that their changing are not going to change the main value of the `desiredTime`.

Comment: Great, I'll take a closer look and answer you later. thanks so much so far!

Comment: unfortunately, your solution works only unevenly, or has some unsightly effects. It works sometimes, nevertheless the time picker can be clicked from time to time between `05` and `00`. that I wanted to avoid actually.

Comment: Yes, this solution prevents the `desiredTime` property from changing and does not prevent the user from changing the number of `b-form-timepicker`. I'll look more for better ways.